# How come values from the Databases are changed often and how to overcome this, Android?

Tags: android, json, android-sqlite, sqlite

Actually, i have created Question and answers. I am getting total 10 questions finally and i have added all those 10 questions in a Question table into Database.

But actually it has runned in a loop. It has shown me 0 to 9 times while executing all those 10 questions from the beginning to end.

But when i do refresh the page and again if run an Emulator,it is shown me as 20 Questions. Later 20 questions became 30 , 40, 50 now 60 questions.

I have had only 10 questions but how come it has been changed as 60 questions now. And in that 60 questions probably repeated questions i have seen there.

Whats the actual problem here ?

Comment: without clearing your questions table you are adding it aging and again.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Without clearing questions table i am adding. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are u saying that everytime u run ur application the total no of questions in ur `QUESTIONS` table is increased by 10? If so then u might have written a piece of code that is adding ur questions everytime u run ur code. Comment that line and run ur app.

If i got ur question wrong then i am sorry and moreover ur question is bit clumsy. Little hard to get whats ur query.

Answer (score 0):

You can add unique index for your questions table

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IndexName ON TableName (fieldName ASC, secondFieldName DESC)

and add smth like ON CONFLICT REPLACE for your table